# how to create multiple UIButton on viewDidLoad (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm sorry but if I have a number of buttons that comes from a plist file ... 
how do I re-create all the buttons?
Example I tried in this way :

```
 func loadSavedButtons() {
 // I extract the number from the plist file 
 var number: AnyObject? = data.valueForKey("NumberOfButton")
 var someNumb: Int = ("\(number!)").toInt()!
 if (someNumb != 0) {
 self.countButton = someNumb
 for (var i=0; i < someNumb; i++) {
```

In This Point I should do

```
 var newButton6: () = CreateButtonWithIndex(i)
 self.view.addSubview(newButton6)
 }}}
```

and

```
 @IBAction func CreateButtonWithIndex(sender: AnyObject){
 let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
 ecc…
 self.view.addSubview(button)
```

but don't go ... i don't have all save button please help me !!!

Comment: Uhhh... use a for loop?

Comment: yes but I can not understand where is the error in object-c and yet it all works ... 
at the start of the app I loaded all the buttons previously saved

Comment: There are two weeks that I slam my head !!! PLEASE ...

Comment: if i enter only
var newButton6: () = self.createButtonWithIndex(i)
I actually displays the last button created but not all previous

Comment: Are you setting the position of each buttons or are they being placed on top of each button? If on top, you will only see the last one.

Answer (score 0):

In your function
Change the following

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

to

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

then after

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

add the following:

```
button = UIButton.new()
```